# How do I resolve the error when trying to play rtsp using jwplayer in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rtsp

How do I resolve the error when trying to play rtsp using jwplayer in react-native?

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import JWPlayer from 'react-native-jw-media-player';

export const CctvPage = () => {
  return (
    <View className={'flex-1 border'}>
      <JWPlayer
        config={{
          file: 'rtsp://210.99.70.120:1935/live/cctv001.stream',
          autostart: true,
          stretching: 'uniform',
          width: '100%',
          aspectratio: '16:9',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

First of all, the following error occurs in the jwplayer option file.

```
TS2769: No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props: PropsType | Readonly<PropsType>): JWPlayer', gave the following error.     Type '{ file: string; autostart: true; stretching: string; width: string; aspectratio: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Config'.       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'file' does not exist in type 'Config'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsType, context: any): JWPlayer', gave the following error.     Type '{ file: string; autostart: true; stretching: string; width: string; aspectratio: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Config'.       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'file' does not exist in type 'Config'.
```

I have used several libraries other than jwplayer.

react-native-vlc-media-player, etc. I don't remember the names, but all the libraries did not work properly.

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.jwplayer:jwplayer-core:4.13.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/4.13.0/jwplayer-core-4.13.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/4.13.0/jwplayer-core-4.13.0.pom
       - file:/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/bnb/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/4.13.0/jwplayer-core-4.13.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/4.13.0/jwplayer-core-4.13.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-core/4.13.0/jwplayer-core-4.13.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-jw-media-player
   > Could not find com.jwplayer:jwplayer-common:4.13.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/4.13.0/jwplayer-common-4.13.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/4.13.0/jwplayer-common-4.13.0.pom
       - file:/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/bnb/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/4.13.0/jwplayer-common-4.13.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/4.13.0/jwplayer-common-4.13.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-common/4.13.0/jwplayer-common-4.13.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-jw-media-player
   > Could not find com.jwplayer:jwplayer-chromecast:4.13.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-chromecast/4.13.0/jwplayer-chromecast-4.13.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-chromecast/4.13.0/jwplayer-chromecast-4.13.0.pom
       - file:/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/bnb/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-chromecast/4.13.0/jwplayer-chromecast-4.13.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-chromecast/4.13.0/jwplayer-chromecast-4.13.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-chromecast/4.13.0/jwplayer-chromecast-4.13.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-jw-media-player
   > Could not find com.jwplayer:jwplayer-ima:4.13.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-ima/4.13.0/jwplayer-ima-4.13.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-ima/4.13.0/jwplayer-ima-4.13.0.pom
       - file:/Users/choiyunseok/kotlinProject/bnb/node_modules/jsc-android/dist/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-ima/4.13.0/jwplayer-ima-4.13.0.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-ima/4.13.0/jwplayer-ima-4.13.0.pom
       - https://www.jitpack.io/com/jwplayer/jwplayer-ima/4.13.0/jwplayer-ima-4.13.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-jw-media-player

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 10s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKX0y.png
```

How to resolve the above error?